# Select all products by manufacturer name

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to import products from an XML and I am new to Xpath. I want to select all products that match a manufacturer name but I cannot figure out how to select it, I only manage to select the manufacturer name. The xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name><![CDATA[Ringke Fusion Samsung Galaxy A3 Smoke Black]]></name>
    <reference><![CDATA[RGK165SM]]></reference>
    <ean13><![CDATA[8809419553075]]></ean13>
    <quantity><![CDATA[0]]></quantity>
    <description_short><![CDATA[<p>Hybrid case with great protection<br></p>]]></description_short>
    <description><![CDATA[bla bla bla]]></description>
    <wholesale_price><![CDATA[4.81]]></wholesale_price>
    <srp><![CDATA[8.53]]></srp>
    <categories_names><![CDATA[]]></categories_names>
    <manufacturer_name><![CDATA[RINGKE]]></manufacturer_name><images_1>https://b2b.homescreen.pl/22/export.jpg</images_1>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name><![CDATA[Ringke Fusion Blackberry Passport Crystal View]]></name>
    <reference><![CDATA[RGK051CL]]></reference>
    <ean13><![CDATA[8809419552948]]></ean13>
    <quantity><![CDATA[0]]></quantity>
    <description_short><![CDATA[<p>Hybrid case with great protection</p>]]></description_short>
    <description><![CDATA[bla bla bla]]></description>
    <wholesale_price><![CDATA[4.81]]></wholesale_price>
    <srp><![CDATA[10.72]]></srp>
    <categories_names><![CDATA[]]></categories_names>
    <manufacturer_name><![CDATA[RINGKE]]></manufacturer_name><images_1>https://b2b.homescreen.pl/26/export.jpg</images_1>
  </product>
</products>
```

What is the query to select all products that match a manufacturer name so that I can get all those products in one file?

Answer (score 1):

Given your example XML above, the [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) expression

```xml
products/product[manufacturer_name='RINGKE']
```

selects all products by the manufacturer with name “RINGKE”. See also [here](http://xpather.com/d4efF8wS). What you’re looking at here are [XML Path predicates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#doc-xpath31-Predicate).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using [@manufacturer_name='RINGKE'] as all of the examples I found were like this and I was getting no results

Comment: Using `@manufacturer_name` describes an attribute on a node itself: `<product manufacturer_name='RINGKE'>...</product>` and not a child node of `<product>`.

Comment: Please feel free to accept the answer if it addresses your question thoroughly! Thank you ☺️